# Huge diaginal matrix in R

Tags: r

The following code causes a memory error:

```
diag(1:100000)
```

Is there any alternative for diag which allows producing a huge diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Longer answer**: I suggest *not* creating a diagonal matrix, because in most situations you can do without it.  To make that clear, consider the most typical matrix operations:

1. Multiply the diagonal matrix `D` by a vector `v` to produce `Dv`.  Instead of maintaining a matrix, keep your "matrix" as a vector `d` of the diagonal elements, and then multiply `d` elementwise by `v`.  Same result.
2. Invert the matrix.  Again, easy: invert each element (of course, only for diagonal matrices is this generally the correct inverse).
3. Various decompositions/eigenvalues/determinants/trace.  Again, these can all be done on the vector `d`.

In short, though it requires a bit of attention in your code, you can always represent a diagonal matrix as a vector, and that should solve your memory issues.

**Shorter answer**: Now, having said all that, of course people have already implemented the above steps implicitly using sparse matrices, which does the above steps under the hood. In R, the `Matrix` package is nice for sparse matrices: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf